# How to call an action after a period of time in a saga function?

Tags: asynchronous, redux, settimeout, redux-saga, saga

I have tried many solutions to execute an action after a period of time, but it seems like nothing is working :

```
export default function* authenticateUserRequest({ payload }) {
  yield put(setIsLogging(true));
  try {
    const { login, password, company, isSaved } = payload;

    const client = yield call(geoRedClient);
    const { data } = yield call(client.auth, {
      login,
      client: company,
      password,
      duree_token: 28800,
    });

    const error = yield call(selectErrorFromResponse, data);

    if (!isNilOrEmpty(error)) {
      yield put(addError('loginError'));
      yield cancel();
    }

    const { token: authToken, ...loginData } = selectCurrentUserLoginFromResponse(data);
    yield call(AsyncStorage.setItem, STORAGE_KEY.authToken, authToken);

    yield put(loginRequestSuccess(loginData));
    //wait 2 seconds
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(addError('loginError'));
  }

  yield put(setIsLogging(false));

  yield delay(30000);
  yield put(logoutRequest());
}
```

I want to log out after 30 seconds, but I got logout immediatly everytime, what you see there is what I have tried.

I tried also this :

```
const delay = time => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));

export default function* authenticateUserRequest({ payload }) {
  yield put(setIsLogging(true));
  try {
      // same actions as before
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(addError('loginError'));
  }

  yield put(setIsLogging(false));

  yield call(delay, 2000);
  yield put(logoutRequest());
}
```

And also this :

```
const sleep = sec => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, sec * 1000));
};

export default function* authenticateUserRequest({ payload }) {
  yield put(setIsLogging(true));
  try {
    
    // same actions as before
    
    yield sleep(20); //wait 2 seconds
    yield put(logoutRequest());
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(addError('loginError'));
  }

  yield put(setIsLogging(false));
}
```

But nothing, always nothing!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried builtin `delay` effect?

Comment: That's what I have tried in the first piece of code.

Comment: Do you see logout request immediately or just ui indication? You have  `yield put(setIsLogging(false));` before `delay`..